# Template copy constructor gives errors

Tags: c++, templates

I try to create a copy constructor to a list. The list has all variables as private members. Is there something special about a constructor in a template that does so this doesn't work?

I get these errors:

```
   1>          consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\circulardoubledirectedlist.h(52) : while compiling class template member function 'CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>::CircularDoubleDirectedList(const CircularDoubleDirectedList<int> &)'
    1>          consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\testdeepcopyingoflist.cpp(25) : see reference to function template instantiation 'CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>::CircularDoubleDirectedList(const CircularDoubleDirectedList<int> &)' being compiled
    1>          consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\testdeepcopyingoflist.cpp(24) : see reference to class template instantiation 'CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>' being compiled
    1>consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\circulardoubledirectedlist.h(57): error C2039: 'dir' : is not a member of 'CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>'
    1>consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\circulardoubledirectedlist.h(62): error C2662: 'void CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>::changeDirection(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>' to 'CircularDoubleDirectedList<int> &'
    1>          Conversion loses qualifiers
    1>consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\circulardoubledirectedlist.h(68): error C2662: 'void CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>::moveCurrent(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>' to 'CircularDoubleDirectedList<int> &'
    1>          Conversion loses qualifiers
    1>consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\circulardoubledirectedlist.h(71): error C2662: 'void CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>::changeDirection(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>' to 'CircularDoubleDirectedList<int> &'
    1>          Conversion loses qualifiers
```

My Code:

```
template <typename T>
CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::CircularDoubleDirectedList(const CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>& other){

    bool changeDir;

    if (other.getCurrentDirection == ICircularDoubleDirectedList::FORWARD){
        changeDir = false;
    }
    else{
        changeDir = true;
        other.changeDirection();
    }

    int size = other.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        this->addAtCurrent(other.getElementAtCurrent());
        other.moveCurrent();
    }
    if (changeDir){
        other.changeDirection();
    }
    this->currentDirection = other.getCurrentDirection();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your copy constructor (rightly) has a `const` reference parameter. However, it looks like you're trying to call non-`const` members on the argument:

```
other.changeDirection(); // this looks like a non-const operation
....

other.moveCurrent();     // this looks like a non-const operation
```

etc. It doesn't make much sense for a copy constructor to modify the thing being copied *from*, but if you really need that then you need the parameter to be non-`const` reference.

Alternatively, if those member functions don't modify the object, make them `const`.

Note that this has nothing to do with templates.

Comment: Use other.move and such is the only way I can get the values or I have to move all the variables to public.

Comment: @Olof If you are just getting values, make the member functions `const`. But names such as `changeDirection()` and `moveCurrent()` suggest something is getting changed.

Comment: Yes they do change. I removed const the parameta is now a non-const reference, however I still get errors like:
> error C3867: 'CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>::getCurrentDirection': function call missing argument list; use '&CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>::getCurrentDirection' to create a pointer to member

Comment: @Olof Looks like you have other, unrelated problems. But bear in mind what I said about copy constructors. It is weird for them to modify the thing being copied from.

Answer (score 1):

The first error doesn't seem to come from this code: there's no use of the name `dir` in the code.

The remaining errors are because you're trying to call non-const member functions on `other`, which is `const`. Either rethink what the constructor should do (since modifying its argument makes it rather confusing), or remove `const` from the parameter to allow modification.